# WordPress core not auto-updating

Tags: automatic-updates

I've got several sites across different servers which all seem to not be updating to the latest security/patch WordPress version. This has been happening for a while, but only on a limited set of sites which use my "new" config/project structure.

I'm presuming there's a setting or something that's causing updates to not occur, but I'm not sure what it is.

**Some settings/server config:**

- Set to update to 'minor' from PHP define `define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', 'minor');`
- Automatic updater isn't disabled `define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', false);`
- WP cron is disabled, but all sites have a real cron job working via the server (runs every 5 to 15 minutes)
- I'm using a similar structure to Bedrock's Roots, with config and composer in the root folder and WordPress in its own folder within.
- No source control folders on the server, but there are several hidden folders/files created by cPanel/host, as well as composer files/folders
- Issue happens across both production and staging servers

**Site Health and other tests:**

- Site Health says all sites are reachable by WordPress.org servers
- Site Health says all WordPress related directories are readable
- The old [Background Update Tester](https://wordpress.org/plugins/background-update-tester/) plugin gave green checks for all tests
- The sites are able to manually update to the latest WordPress core version

Does anyone know what may be causing the updates to not attempt, or something I can run to test to find the cause?